# ASP session variables overwritten

Tags: variables, session, iis, asp-classic, conflict

We have two different ASP web applications that share the same session variable names. When a single user opens the two applications simultaneously from the same browser there is a conflict caused by session vars that get overwritten. What would be the best approach (if any) to fix this apart from using different session names of course.

Comment: Create separate application pools, it sounds like both ASP Web Applications are using the same App Pool in IIS at the moment. Sessions are stored in memory against the Application Pool, so running two or more Web Applications in the same Application Pool with Sessions enabled is going to be messy. Remember with different App Pools ASP Web Applications can use the same session variable names without fear of clashes.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are sharing the same application pool for both the sites in IIS. You should allocate separate application pool for each site to avoid this clash.

The Reason is, Each application pool will create and allocate a new worker process which will keep the assigned web application as unique.

Hope this helps and clarifies.